# How do I fix an issue I'm having using Parse for push notifications for an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications).

I've been able to follow along except when I get to step 10: Right-click on it, select "Export Apple…", and save it as a .p12 file. Do not enter an export password when prompted!

When I right click on the certificate in KeyChain, I don't see this option for "Export Apple". Did I miss a step? How do I troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to export a certificate as a .p12 file, select the certificate in Keychain, click "File" -> "Export Items...", select .p12 as the file format and save it. Leave the password field on the appearing popup view blank to save without password.